# Need to count character

Tags: r, integer, character

I have a `dataframe LoopVariable` and the following couple of lines of code:

```
print(unique(LoopVariable[,"Job..R"]))
[1] "14047/2" "18331/3"
```

My output are two character and that is all good. My question now is: How can I count my output for further calculation usage? In other words: I have two characters and I need them to be as an integer for further calculation usage. In my example here the integer value would be `"2"`.

Comment: Are you looking for `length`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `length()` function for this. You can find more about the function by typing `?length` into your console.

This is likely what you should expect:

```
length(unique(LoopVariable[,"Job..R"]))
[1] 2
```